# SQL data comparison

Tags: sql

I have some smart measurement devices that store data in SQL. These devices record data once a day, and I need to be able to take the most current data and compare it to a previous day's data. The device is a counter with a dial. We store the current dial reading and date of dial reading in SQL.
The condition would be taking current dial reading, and checking if any previous day's dial reading is MORE than the current day's (e.g. 6/13/13 dial read is less than 6/10/13).
Problem is I don't know how to make SQL lookback for a time where the dial reading is less than "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" and have it display that data.

Table structure is as follows:

```
-------------------------------------    
DeviceNo| RecordingDate| DialReading|
-------------------------------------     
1234    | 6/10/13      | 504
-------------------------------------
1232    | 6/10/13      | 8899
```

Comment: just use condition in where with RecordingDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, let me know if it does not work, I cant remember if a CTE's alias can be used outside the CTE, if it can the alias may cause a problem, I will just re-name them is that is the case.

```
--cte selects readings information based on current database system timestamp
WITH cte AS(
SELECT d.DeviceNo, r.RecordingDate, r.DialReading
FROM Devices d
inner join Modules m  on d.DeviceID = m.DeviceID
inner join Recordings r on m.ModuleID = r.ModuleID
WHERE  r.RecordingDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

--selects everything where the device numbers match cte's result set
--where the dial reading is higher than todays
--and finally where the recordingDate is less than the
--current database system timestamp

SELECT d.DeviceNo, r.RecordingDate, r.DialReading
FROM Devices d
inner join Modules m  on d.DeviceID = m.DeviceID
inner join Recordings r on m.ModuleID = r.ModuleID
WHERE cte.DeviceNo = d.DeviceNo
AND r.DialReading > cte.DialReading
AND r.RecordingDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that DeviceNo is joined to the ReadingTable. How would the script change in this instance? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2482608 
What is the actual name of the table I have referred to as ReadingTable, what is the name of the table that it is joined to to retrieve the DeviceNo and finally what field links them?

Comment: select Devices.DeviceNo, Recordings.RecordingDate, Recordings.DialReading
from Devices
inner join Modules on Devices.DeviceID = Modules.DeviceID
inner join Recordings on Modules.ModuleID = Recordings.ModuleID

Comment: @user2482608 Give that a try and as I mention in the answer let me know if the alias's are causing problems

Comment: i have fine tuned it a tad so that no syntax errors occur by starting the query with GO and by CTE i add parenthesis to call the desired columns.
BUT, on the 2nd part of the query, when I run it, the columns show correctly, but no data is in them, despite changing the CURRENT_DATE TO "CURRENT_DATE -7".

Comment: ALSO, the second portion of the query runs (shows data) if I take out AND r.DialReading > cte.DialReading
AND r.RecordingDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.............leaving just WHERE cte.DeviceNo = d.DeviceNo

Comment: @user2482608 Does it have to be CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or can it be getdate(), try hard coding in todays date maybe to work out if its the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP thats filtering everything out.